# How to give html actions/variables to flask submit button

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a flask app with a form that takes awhile for my backend to process. I want to display a loading gif while this happens to refrain people from refreshing or resubmitting.

My current flask form submit html looks like this:

```
<div class="form=group">
    {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-outline-info') }}
</div>
```

I am aware that the common solution is to make the submit button an html input as follows

```
<input type="submit" name="anything_submit" value="Submit" onclick="loading();">
```

Where "loading();" is a javascript function to display the gif. However, I would like to keep the button I have with the form.submit. It looks better and is uniform across all my code. The flask documentation says that the form field "Represents an <input type="submit">", which is the same format as above. This leads me to believe I should, theoretically, be able to put the onclick="loading();" variable somewhere in the form or the submit button to attain the same result. I tried

```
<div class="form=group">
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
      function loading(){
          $("#loading").show();
          $("#content").hide();       
      }
    // ]]></script>
    {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-outline-info' onclick="loading();") }}
</div>
```

with no luck. Any ideas? The css I used is here.

```
div#loading {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: none;
    background: url(/static/loading.gif) no-repeat;
    cursor: wait;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change:

> type="submit" to type="button"

```
<input type="button" name="anything_submit" value="Submit" onclick="loading();">
```

And you need add in your function loading();

```
$("#loading").show();
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

this allows us to generate a submit action:

> document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

In any case the onclick event is wrong, you can use onsubmit:

```
{{ form.submit(class='btn btn-outline-info' onsubmit="loading();") }}
```